# Python - How to send an html email and attach an image with Python?

Tags: python, email-attachments, smtplib

I am getting an "error: ValueError: Cannot convert mixed to alternative."

I get this error when I insert the open image and msg.add_attachment block (highlighted in btw #### ####). Without it, the code runs fine. I need to send the email as html and with the image attachment.

```
import os
import imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib


EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIL-USER')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL-PASS')

Message0 = "HelloWorld1"
Message1 = "HelloWorld2"

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Hello WORLD'
msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS

msg.set_content('This is a plain text email, see HTML format')

########################################################################
with open('screenshot.png', 'rb') as f:
    file_data = f.read()
    file_type = imghdr.what(f.name)
    file_name = f.name

msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='image', subtype=file_type, filename=file_name)
#########################################################################

msg.add_alternative("""\
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1 style="color:Blue;">Hello World</h1>
                {Message0}
                {Message1}
        </body>
    </html>
    """.format(**locals()), subtype='html')

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
    print("email sent")
```

For the end result, I need to be able to send an email via Python and attach images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An e-mail can consist of a single part, or it can be a multi-part message.
If it is a multi-part message, it will usually be either a `multipart/alternative`, or a `multipart/mixed`.

- **`multipart/alternative`** means there are 2 or more versions of the same content (e.g. plain text and html)
- **`multipart/mixed`**  is used when multiple different contents need to be packed together (e.g. an email and an attachment)

What actually happens when `multipart` is used is that email consists of a "multipart" container which contains additional parts, e.g. for text+html it is something like this:

- `multipart/alternative` part

  - `text/plain` part
  - `text/html` part

In case of an email with attachment, you can have something like this:

- `multipart/mixed` part

  - `text/plain` part
  - `image/png` part

So, the container is either `mixed` or `alternative`, but cannot be both. So, how to have both? You can nest them, e.g.:

- `multipart/mixed` part

  - `multipart/alternative` part

    - `text/plain` part
    - `text/html` part
  - `image/png` part

So, now you have an email which consists of a message and an attachment, and the message has both plain text and html.

---

Now, in code, this is the basic idea:

```
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
msg['From'] = 'from@email'
msg['To'] = 'to@email'

msg.set_content('This is a plain text')
msg.add_attachment(b'xxxxxx', maintype='image', subtype='png', filename='image.png')

# Now there are plain text and attachment.
# HTML should be added as alternative to the plain text part:

text_part, attachment_part = msg.iter_parts()
text_part.add_alternative("<p>html contents</p>", subtype='html')
```

---

BTW, you can then see what is in each part this way:

```
>>> plain_text_part, html_text_part = text_part.iter_parts()
>>> print(plain_text_part)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a plain text
```

---

```
>>> print(html_text_part)
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0

<p>html contents</p>
```

---

```
>>> print(attachment_part)
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"
MIME-Version: 1.0

eHh4eHh4
```

---

```
>>> print(msg)
Subject: Subject
From: from@email
To: to@email
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============2219697219721248811=="

--===============2219697219721248811==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============5680305804901241482=="

--===============5680305804901241482==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a plain text

--===============5680305804901241482==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0

<p>html contents</p>

--===============5680305804901241482==--

--===============2219697219721248811==
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"
MIME-Version: 1.0

eHh4eHh4

--===============2219697219721248811==--
```

Comment: For more details about multipart, see [RFC  2046](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046)

Comment: @ zvone thanks for the code and explanation. I am able to add one attachment. But when i attempt multiple attachments (i.e. a few pictures), I get the below error with text_part, attachment_part = msg.iter_parts().                                                                             ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complementary example to the one provided by @zvone. The difference here is that I want to have a mail with 2 versions. One in plain-text with an image as an attachement. The other part being the html with embedded image.

So the layout of the mail is like so:

- `multipart/mixed part`

  - `multipart/alternative part`

    - `multipart/related part`         (html with img)

      - `text/html part`
      - `image/png part`
    - `text/plain part`                (plain text)
  - `image/png part`                    (attachement)

##### plain-text version: *textfile.txt*

```
Hello World
```

##### html version: *mail_content.html*

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <img src="cid:{graph_example_img_cid}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

And of course the Python code (tested for `Python 3.10`). The embedding of the image follows the example from latest [Python Standard Library of `email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

##### Python code: *main.py*

```py
# var
mail_server: str = "****smtp****"
user: str = "****@****.com"
me = user
you = user

# imports
import smtplib # mail actual sending function
import imghdr # And imghdr to find the types of our images
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid
import datetime

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
textfile_filepath: str = "textfile.txt"
with open(textfile_filepath) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'Test Email with 2 versions'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# attachements
# Open the files in binary mode.  Use imghdr to figure out the
# MIME subtype for each specific image.
image_filepath: str = "test_image.png"
with open(image_filepath, 'rb') as fp:
    img_data = fp.read()
    msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image', subtype=imghdr.what(None, img_data))

text_part, attachment_part = msg.iter_parts()

## HTML alternative using Content ID
html_content_filepath: str = "mail_content.html"
graph_cid = make_msgid()
with open(html_content_filepath) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    #msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
    raw_html: str = fp.read()
    # note that we needed to peel the <> off the msgid for use in the html.
    html_content: str = raw_html.format(graph_example_img_cid=graph_cid[1:-1])

    # add to email message 
    text_part.add_alternative(html_content,subtype='html')

# Now add the related image to the html part.
with open(image_filepath, 'rb') as img:
    text_part, html_part = text_part.iter_parts()
    html_part.add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'jpeg', cid=graph_cid)

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server)
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()

# log
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print("{} >>> Email sent (From: {}, To: {})".format(
    current_time.isoformat(), me, you
))
```