# ValueError: Cannot convert mixed to alternative - Sending Email with Python

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send a styled bootstrap HTML template to email with the help of smtplib and EmailMessage. I have used f string to format the file. But, I am facing ValueError: Cannot convert mixed to the alternative. I could not address the problem. It should have work but couldn't be able to think much. Where did I do wrong?.

In **emailsender.py**

```
import smtplib
import imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage

#Credentials
sender_email = "sender127@gmail.com"
password = 'password231'
receiver_email = "reciever9882@gmail.com"

smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465)
smtp.login(sender_email, password)

message = EmailMessage() #Instantiate EmailMessage
 
with open('/email.png', 'rb') as file_obj:
    fdata = file_obj.read()
    ftype = imghdr.what(file_obj.name)
    print('Type:'+ftype)
    fname = file_obj.name
    print('Name of file:'+fname) 

message["Subject"] = "Email Test"
message["From"] = sender_email 
message["To"] = receiver_email 
message.set_content("This is a test version!")
#message.attach('django notes.pdf')
message.add_attachment(fdata, maintype ="image", subtype = ftype,
                       filename=fname)
message.add_alternative(f"""\n\n
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
</head>
<body>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="container py-4">
        <header class="pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center text-dark text-decoration-none">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="32" class="me-2" viewBox="0 0 118 94"
                    role="img">
                    <title>Bootstrap</title>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M24.509 0c-6.733 0-11.715 5.893-11.492 12.284.214 6.14-.064 14.092-2.066 20.577C8.943 39.365 5.547 43.485 0 44.014v5.972c5.547.529 8.943 4.649 10.951 11.153 2.002 6.485 2.28 14.437 2.066 20.577C12.794 88.106 17.776 94 24.51 94H93.5c6.733 0 11.714-5.893 11.491-12.284-.214-6.14.064-14.092 2.066-20.577 2.009-6.504 5.396-10.624 10.943-11.153v-5.972c-5.547-.529-8.934-4.649-10.943-11.153-2.002-6.484-2.28-14.437-2.066-20.577C105.214 5.894 100.233 0 93.5 0H24.508zM80 57.863C80 66.663 73.436 72 62.543 72H44a2 2 0 01-2-2V24a2 2 0 012-2h18.437c9.083 0 15.044 4.92 15.044 12.474 0 5.302-4.01 10.049-9.119 10.88v.277C75.317 46.394 80 51.21 80 57.863zM60.521 28.34H49.948v14.934h8.905c6.884 0 10.68-2.772 10.68-7.727 0-4.643-3.264-7.207-9.012-7.207zM49.948 49.2v16.458H60.91c7.167 0 10.964-2.876 10.964-8.281 0-5.406-3.903-8.178-11.425-8.178H49.948z"
                        fill="currentColor"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="fs-4">Jumbotron example</span>
            </a>
        </header>

        <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
            <div class="container-fluid py-5">
                <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Custom jumbotron</h1>
                <p class="col-md-8 fs-4">Using a series of utilities, you can create this jumbotron, just like the one
                    in previous versions of Bootstrap. Check out the examples below for how you can remix and restyle it
                    to your liking.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">Example button</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row align-items-md-stretch">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="h-100 p-5 text-white bg-dark rounded-3">
                    <h2>Change the background</h2>
                    <p>Swap the background-color utility and add a `.text-*` color utility to mix up the jumbotron look.
                        Then, mix and match with additional component themes and more.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="button">Example button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="h-100 p-5 bg-light border rounded-3">
                    <h2>Add borders</h2>
                    <p>Or, keep it light and add a border for some added definition to the boundaries of your content.
                        Be sure to look under the hood at the source HTML here as we've adjusted the alignment and
                        sizing of both column's content for equal-height.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Example button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="pt-3 mt-4 text-muted border-top">
            © 2021
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
        """ ,subtype="html")
smtp.send_message(message)
```

**Tracebacks here**->
[click here to view the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuzYu.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618882/python-how-to-send-an-html-email-and-attach-an-image-with-python) answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, It does. But I have a question? . It seems all the styles and bootstrap cdn don't work?. So, How can I render with some good styling when I check out my mail in Gmail?

Comment: Because external style sheets and scripts are not allowed for safety reasons.